# find using regexp and echo matches

Tags: linux, unix, regex, find

I have about 50 users in */home/* directory and I have cloned a git repository to everyone:

Executed at /home/ as root user:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name . -prune -exec git clone /shared/repos/project_xpto.git {}/www/xpto/ \;
```

Now I need to set owners to these cloned repositories.

I want to execute *chown user_folder_name:development -R ./user/www/xpto/* for each cloned repo.

Then I started with:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype sed -regex "./\([A-Za-z0-9-_]\).*" -type d -exec echo {}/ \;
```

And I want to envolve to:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype sed -regex "./\([A-Za-z0-9-_]\).*" -type d -exec chown ${expr1}:development {}/www/xpto/ -R
```

I know ${expr1} does not exists. I just wanna know how to return my first matched regexp pattern, then I will get just username, without dots and slashes, from each folder to set owner.

Comment: Why not just pass the folder name to as an argument to the script, and have it extract the username from the folder name?

Answer (score 0):

The `find` is a real requirement?

I'm thinking something like

```
ls -1d /home/*/www/xpto | awk -F/ '{print "chown",$3":development",$0}'
```

(I'm assuming that your usernames are the same of the home folder names.)

With the above code you will get the commands you can then run with `xargs` or in a temporary script.

Comment: In general `find` is better than [parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski in general you're right, but, as you can see, this is not a general question and the "awk" only prints every command.